# CKAN API call to return metadata for all resource_views on a CKAN website

Tags: ckan

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to extract the metadata for all resource views (i.e. dataset previews) for a website via the CKAN API?

As per the API documentation, I know it is possible to return to the metadata of a particular resource view via ckan.logic.action.get.resource_view_show?id=foo or a list of views for a particular resource via ckan.logic.action.get.resource_view_list?id=foo. However, I would like to return resource_view metadata for all views on a particular site. Any help here greatly appreciated.